# Delete multiple values from Redis Cache using @CacheEvict Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, redis

first time using Redis (for caching purposes), I have the cache working for getting all values and updating them, but for delete, since I want to allow for functionality for a user to delete multiple values at once instead of doing them one at a time (A user can select multiple records and the delete would be done for all of those, or if a single value is selected, then only that would be deleted)

Now when I delete a **Single** record, then it would be removed from the cache when I check, but when I attempt to delete multiple records, those values still remain in the cache.

---

**Delete Endpoint**

```
    // In the request, a list of Ids can be passed or even just a single Id, and then those records will be deleted appropriately
    @CacheEvict(value="Post", key="#postId")
    @DeleteMapping("/posts/{postId}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> deletePosts(@PathVariable List<Long> postId, Principal principal) {
        postService.deleteMultiplePosts(postId, principal.getName());
        // When a record is deleted, just return all the remaining records as a response 
        return new ResponseEntity<>(createMapForPageContents(postService.findAllActivePostsByPostCreator(principal.getName(), PageRequest.of(0, 5))), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

**Service method**

```
    public void deleteMultiplePosts(List<Long> postIdList, String emailAddress) {
        List<Post> posts = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < postIdList.size(); i++) {
            posts.add(findPostById(postIdList.get(i), emailAddress));
        }
        postRepository.deleteAll(posts);
    }
```

---

The delete works and reflects in MySQL, but not the cache (Only when attempting to delete multiple values from the cache, not just one)

I'm using Postman to test requests

Answer (score 0):

you should add `allEntries = false` in your  `@CacheEvict(value="Post", key="#postId")` so you should be having

```
 @CacheEvict(value="Post",allEntries = false , key="#postId")
```